# How to prevent users from seeing stored procedures and other securables in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a desktop app developed using vb.net. It runs on SQL Server 2008. After creating a new login and user I realised that when they login they can browse through and see securables like the stored procedures. I want to prevent anyone from seeing the stored procedures, triggers etc. But I want them to be able to only execute them. I don't know how to achieve this. Please help me on this.

Comment: you want them to be able to execute them, but not see them? I think if you give a user execute permission to a procedure, then by implication that user must be able to see that it's there. And what's the harm - if they can't modify them, and can't access the underlying tables, what's the problem? Most users won't even know how to log into SQL Server directly, or have the tools installed to do so.

Comment: You can use `with encription` option. Read [CREATE PROCEDURE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) for specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deny a user/role rights to view the DDL definition. It will not prevent them from seeing object names.

For example,

```
DENY VIEW DEFINITION ON dbo.stored_procedure TO GWashington
```